# Find out which sharepoint server is using the databases

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, search, sql-server

I've found one of my SQL servers has all the usual `Sharepoint Search Server` application databases but I can't figure out why they are on this particular SQL server.

Is there a SQL query that I can use to find out the name of the `Sharepoint server`? Or perhaps a Powershell command I can run?

Comment: How many servers in your farm ? should you elaborate more what do you need specifically for I can't figure out why they are on this particular SQL server. ?

Comment: 1. It is a self contained server. I think I may have created a test SharePoint instance but I can't remember where. I've just come across the databases though so want to trace my instance.

Comment: you can confirm which instance of SQL your SharePoint been connected from Central Administration , if you have the access to SharePoint.

Comment: What if I can't locate the SharePoint server?

Comment: what you mean cant locate the SharePoint server? You dont know about SharePoint server, how you are accessing the SharePoint?

Comment: I'm not accessing it at all. I think I set up a test Sharepoint farm and used this SQL server for it. Unfortunately I cannot remember which server I installed Sharepoint to, so I was looking to find it via the database somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from any SharePoint server run the below command, it will tell you on about every database is being used in the farm.

```
Get-SPDatabase | Select displayname, NormalizedDataSource, Type
```

Or go `Central admin > Upgrade and migration > Review Database Status` on this page, you will get list of database being used in SharePoint along with Sql Server information.

Couple of things to try to nail it down.

[Run the below script](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2008/03/how-to-see-active-connections-for-each.html), which will tell you any active connection with login name.

```
 SELECT db_name(dbid) as DatabaseName, count(dbid) as NoOfConnections,
loginame as LoginName
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE dbid > 0
GROUP BY dbid, loginame
```

Now if you run the below built in store proc then you will see from which server it is being connected.

```
exec sp_who
exec sp_who2
```

Comment: This only tells me about the server I'm connected to. What I'm trying to find is the mystery Sharepoint instance that has created databases on my server. Please re-read the question and comments

Comment: are you seeing any active connection to that Search Database in SQL server? Do you have search service application in your farm?

Comment: check th eupdated answer

Comment: Got it! Running sp_who gave me various connections but more importantly a hostname. I've now tracked down the rogue Sharepoint server. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

From a SharePoint Server you can simply run

```
$db = (Get-SPDatabase)[0]
$db.Server
```

[image]

From SQL Server it's a bit tricker, but you can get the applications using this SQL Server by running the following TSQL command

```
SELECT program_name, count(*)
FROM
Master..sysprocesses
WHERE ecid=0
GROUP BY program_name
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Now the output doesn't give you the farm, but it gives you the applications. In my case

```
SharePoint[OWSTIMER][1][Cloud_Search_Service_Application]                                                                       
SharePoint[OWSTIMER][1][SP2016_Config]                                                                                          
SharePoint[w3wp][2][SP2016_Config]                                                                                              
SharePoint[noderunner][3][Cloud_Search_Service_Application]                                                                     
SharePoint[OWSTIMER][1][Cloud_Search_Service_Application_CrawlStore]                                                            
.Net SqlClient Data Provider                                                                                                    
SharePoint[w3wp][2][SP2016-Content-MySite]                                                                                      
SharePoint[w3wp][2][SP2016-Content-PR4]                                                                              
SharePoint[noderunner][3][SP2016_Config]
```

I can see the Service Application name in the farm, in my case Cloud_Search_Service_Application, which makes it easier to identify which SharePoint farm is using this SQL Server. I have Hybrid Search switched on, which has a Clous Search Service Application named the same.

Comment: Hi Benny, this is helpful but just tells me I have a Sharepoint Foundation instance/farm. I need to know the server name but it seems that it might be a more difficult task than I thought!